# Incorrect position of tooltip only in new version of dojo 1.7

Tags: javascript, charts, dojo, dojox.charting

When i updated my version of dojo from 1.6 to 1.7.1 i found an issue in the position of the tolltips in `ClusteredBars`. Even in the Dojo Toolkit SDK 1.7.1 this occurs.

demo

http://jsbin.com/utesoz/2/edit

Any idea ? I think this problem is probably a bug

Comment: I see you only use the 1.6 css file in your test. Are you sure that wasn't changed for 1.7?

Answer (score 0):

I think not.
Review your code, it is plenty of errors. Also look at:

```
chart1.addPlot("default", {
    type: 'Markers',
    animate: {
        duration: 1000
    },
    type: "ClusteredBars"
});
```

you are using type twice. Check you are filling the series in the right way.
Cheers